# DebeziumIO read with SQL Server not streaming with Apache beam in GCP

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, pipeline, apache-beam, debezium

I did configure the standalone Debezium and tested the streaming. After that I created a pipeline as follows

```
pipeline.apply("Read from DebeziumIO",
               DebeziumIO.<String>read()
                 .withConnectorConfiguration(
                   DebeziumIO.ConnectorConfiguration.create()
                     .withUsername("user")
                     .withPassword("password")
                     .withHostName("hostname")
                     .withPort("1433")
                     .withConnectorClass(SqlServerConnector.class)
                     .withConnectionProperty("database.server.name", "customer")
                     .withConnectionProperty("database.dbname", "test001")
                     .withConnectionProperty("database.include.list", "test002")
                     .withConnectionProperty("include.schema.changes", "true")
                     .withConnectionProperty("database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")  
                     .withConnectionProperty("database.history.kafka.topic", "schema-changes.inventory") 
                     .withConnectionProperty("connect.keep.alive", "false")               
                     .withConnectionProperty("connect.keep.alive.interval.ms", "200")
                  ).withFormatFunction(new SourceRecordJson.SourceRecordJsonMapper()).withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
      )
```

When I start the pipeline using DirectRunner, datastream is not captured by the pipeline. In my pipeline code I just added code to dump the data into console for the time being.

Also from the log I observe that the Debezium is being started and stopped frequently. Is that by design?
Also when there is a change made into the DB (INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE), I dont find it being reflected in the logs.

So my question is,

1. **Configuration what I provided is that sufficient?**
2. **Why is the pipeline not being triggered when there is a change?**
3. **What additional steps I need to perform to get it working?**

Comment: 200ms for connect.keep.alive.interval.ms seems quite low - the default is 60,000ms (1 minute).

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you connecting to? Debezium requires that CDC (change data capture) is available, which requires at least SQL Server 2016 SP1, Standard or Enterprise editions.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2019. Debezium standalone server works fine with this setup. Only the pipeline got issues.

Comment: I modified the keep alive to 60,000 ms and below is the log
Mar 24, 2022 9:45:26 AM start
INFO:    connect.keep.alive.interval.ms = 60000
INFO: Started database history recovery
INFO: Finished database history recovery of 1 change(s) in 0 ms
INFO: Metrics registered
INFO: Context created
INFO: Starting streaming
INFO: Last position recorded in offsets is 0000006c:000000d8:0001
INFO: Stopping down connector
INFO: Finished streaming
Mar 24, 2022 9:45:27 AM
INFO: Connection gracefully closed
Mar 24, 2022 9:45:28 AM 
INFO: Connection gracefully closed

Comment: You can see from the log, irrespective of the timeout, connection gets  closed in less than 2 seconds. Also on every connect, it takes a snapshot informs that "A previous offset indicating a completed snapshot has been found" and new changes are never streamed.

Comment: One thing to note is that DebeziumIO needs to restart debezium multiple times because it needs to commit data as it consumes it. Can you try removing `"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers"` and `"database.history.kafka.topic"`? Beam's DebeziumIO caches the database history internally

Comment: Removed the history related configs. It is still behaving the same. Almost within every 2 seconds it gets started and stopped.

Comment: As an update here - the `"include.schema.changes"` attribute seems to be causing the issue (it's a bug either way), but if you set it to "false" you should be able to continue

Answer (score 0):

Restarting debezium multiple times can it cause performance impacts. Since it creates a jdbc connection.